# using TypeScript for partial application

Tags: typescript

I like using object literals as a function argument because it allows me to label the argument names. I thought there would be a type-safe generic way to do partial function application on these types of functions. Suppose a function takes an argument of type X. And then I run that function through another function called "partial" where I supply a Partial of X, it could return a new function that expects just the missing values. Easiest to see with an example below. The nice thing here is that with my "partial" function I can supply any number or combination of arguments and get a result function that clearly indicates what is still needed.

```
function partial<Args, Fixed extends Partial<Args>, Result>(fn: (args: Args) => Result, fixed: Fixed) {
    type Unspecified = { [P in Exclude<keyof Args, keyof Fixed>]: Args[P] };
    const result = (args: Unspecified) => {
        const combined = {};
        Object.assign(combined, fixed, args);
        return fn(combined as Args);
    };
    return result as ({} extends Unspecified ? () => Result : (args: Unspecified) => Result);
}

interface AddThreeNumbersArgs {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
    caption: string;
}

function addThreeNumbers(args: AddThreeNumbersArgs) {
    return `${args.caption} ${args.a + args.b + args.c}`;
}

test("fix one number and the caption", () => {
    const f = partial(addThreeNumbers, { b: 10, caption: "The answer is:" });
    const result = f({ a: 1, c: 25 });
    expect(result).toBe("The answer is: 36");
});
```

This all works nicely for the AddThreeNumbers example above. But it does NOT work when the function argument is a generic - see below - and I don't know why. Instead the result of `partial` is a function that takes NO arguments rather than the missing pieces. Do any TypeScript gurus know why?

```
interface ConcatenateArrayArgs<TItem> {
    first: TItem[],
    second: TItem[]
}

function concatenate<T>(args: ConcatenateArrayArgs<T>) {
    return [...args.first, ...args.second];
}

test("concatenate", () => {
    const result = concatenate({ first: [1, 2, 3], second: [4, 5, 6] });
    expect(result).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
});

test("fix first array in concatenate to array of numbers", () => {
    const f = partial(concatenate, { first: [1, 2, 3] });
    // expect f to take a { second: [4,5,6] } here but instead
    // f is a function with no arguments
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have run into the issue in [Microsoft/TypeScript#9366](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9366); TypeScript doesn't have great support for type inference involving [higher-rank function types](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/115/higher-rank-and-higher-kinded-types).  UPDATE: The support added in TS3.4 for [inferring higher order function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) isn't general enough to help you here, unfortunately; the compiler can now *propagate* some generic type parameters from an input function to an output function (e.g., if `concatenate` is generic, then `partial(concatenate, ...)` will also be generic), but it can't arbitrarily *specify* a generic type parameter in the input function (e.g., plug `number` in for the type parameter in `concatenate` to make the output function non-generic).  So, for example, [microsoft/TypeScript#25256](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25256) is still a design limitation.

The only workaround I can think of is for you to explicitly specify types somewhere.  You could, for instance, lower the rank of your callback function to a non-generic one, as in:

```
const f = partial(
  concatenate as (x: ConcatenateArrayArgs<number>)=>number, 
  { first: [1, 2, 3] }
);
```

And then inference works as you expect.  Or you could explicitly specify the type parameters in the call to `partial()` so that *it* is essentially non-generic and there is no inference for the compiler to get wrong:

```
const r = partial<
  ConcatenateArrayArgs<number>,
  { first: number[] },
  number[]
>(concatenate, { first: [1, 2, 3] });
```

Those both work, but are not particularly satisfying.  Hope that at least points you in the right direction.  Good luck!

Comment: The linked GitHub issue was closed in 2019 when they added support for higher-rank function types: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that feature doesn't support the use case here, but I've updated the answer to reflect that.